# Cron syntax interpreter?

Tags: cron

Does anyone know of a tool that will given a cron string for example * * * 1 * * tell you what that string translates to?

I know it's not rocket science but I want to be sure that I'm constructing the correct interval for a scheduled task.

Comment: Whats the desired output, seeing as that above line matches infinitely many date-times?

Comment: Desired output for above would be "once a month" or something like that.

Comment: Desired outcome would be: `(try to) execute every file in the home directory` every minute in January.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just found this, was exactly what I was looking for and it seems like what you want too: http://cronchecker.net/

Comment: This one is not able to parse this cron: 30 07,11 * * 1-6 and some others too.

Comment: @Guillaume: I recently rebuilt cronchecker.net and it can handle many more cron statements that it couldn't previously, including the one you mention. Please [let me know](https://github.com/pbyrne/cron-checker/issues) if you run into any more that don't work properly.

Comment: @pbyrne Doesn't parse `00 30 22 * * *`. Displays the message: `We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.`

Answer (score 2):

I just found that this web app is more able to process cron expr:
http://crontranslator.appspot.com/

I found this other one that let you build you cron expr from a form, and that can be handy too:
http://www.cronmaker.com/